# Heroku Error H14 (No web processes running)

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

Pretty sure some people encountered this problem before.

Followed all the instructions to setup node and npm. When pushing to heroku there were no errors. But when I open the app, it shows "Application Error"

```
heroku ps
```

returns

```
Process  State      Command       
-------  ---------  ------------  
main.1   up for 1m  node main.js
```

while

```
heroku logs
```

returns

```
Error H14 (No web processes running) -> GET mewtwo.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I tried restarting the app with `heroku restart` but still get the same error. Google around and there were no other solution other than `heroku restart`. Anyone tried other methods ?

Comment: Are you certain you've bought web-worker instances?

Comment: do I have to buy? I am just following the setup tutorial - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs, I suppose it's free unless you want to add more?

Comment: found the quote "Running more than one dyno for an extended period may incur charges to your account". I am only running one.

Comment: Hrm, perhaps it _is_ free to start: http://www.heroku.com/pricing#1-1  has a "Free -750 Hours" column...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The name of your web process must be `web`, and this is the process that Heroku will always scale to '1' on initial deploy.

Other services in the Procfile can be called what you want, but you need to scale them initially (so you can have dev only processes in there if you want).

More information here: http://neilmiddleton.com/the-procfile-is-your-friend/
(the cached version: https://web.archive.org/web/20130926005616/http://www.neilmiddleton.com/the-procfile-is-your-friend)

Comment: I would add that if he really want's to have a named process as "main", that has nothing to do with web (for work process, there should be no http routing), he could do it by scaling web=0 main=1, and then restart

Comment: No need to restart on scaling.

Answer (score 83):

I had the same problem, but for me it was because I needed to run `heroku ps:scale web=1`

Comment: This is needed if you initially forget to push a `Procfile`. In that case, even pushing one later or running `heroku ps:restart` will not help.

Comment: i wasn't seeing anything after adding a Procfile.  but then setting the ps:scale web=1 got things up and running right away.  thanks!

Comment: Happened to me after duplicating an app using `heroku fork`

Comment: Happened to me after pushing code with a procfile named with the wrong case.

Comment: Whatever I did initially, this worked for me... Thanks, Jeff

Comment: update as of dec 2022. After recent policy changes on heroku and it seems free dynos are not available anymore. need to subscribe to a minimal conf and run this command again.

Comment: in Heroku now you can first choose pay either "Subscribe to Eco" across your projects where if your dyno receives no web traffic in a 30-minute period it sleeps and becomes active when it receives traffic again after a short delay, or if you choose "Basic" for a specific project you can avoid that sleeping, then run either `heroku ps:scale web=1:Basic; heroku restart`

Answer (score 3):

Full disclosure, I solved this problem by turning it on.

Heroku Application Overview tab > click Configure Dyno > click the pencil icon > click toggle switch to On position > click confirm

Comment: Little addition. if the toggle is already on. First turn it off and confirm and next turn it on and confirm.

Answer (score 0):

I guess my problem was this, i had a python script in my node application which led heroku to believe that it is a python app, also i did not add a procfile since i expected the build bots to automatically detect that its a node app, so after setting up the procfile , then specifying the node and npm versions inside engines key in package.json, and changing the buildpack type to heroku/node, i got my app running.