# heroku: "no such type as worker"

Tags: heroku

On Heroku, I'm trying to setup a worker-only (no web) dyno.

My Profile has:

```
worker: python common/elections_updater.py
```

But after I push and try to scale, I get this:

```
$heroku scale web=0 worker=1
Scaling web processes... done, now running 0
Scaling worker processes... failed
! No such type as worker
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `web` process on heroku has a special meaning (other process you can name anything). Perhaps there's an error because it's missing. Somewhat related info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9972951/1006036)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It turned out that while foreman doesn't care, Heroku doesn't like it if you don't have a space between your process type and your process command in your profile. The following did not work:

```
worker:python myapp.py
```

whereas the following does work:

```
worker: python myapp.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You say your Profile has such and such, but it needs to be Procfile

Comment: It was a typo. I meant "Procfile", the file is spelled correctly.